EF Core does not debug with large database
I am just implementing a new app, and wanted to use EF Core instead of ADO.NET. Therefore, I took the necessary steps to implement this which worked correctly as far as I can tell. The MySQL database behind is relatively large. It has about 800 tables and a dump would result in about 3 GB.
But when I want to debug, it always does not even start, but gives the following error:

CS0041 Unexpected error writing debug information -- 'Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program

So, my question, can I not work with EF Core and databases of the mentioned size? Or is there maybe a possibility how to fix this?
Further information:

.NET: 4.8
EF Core: 3.1
RAM: 64 GB

And when I start the release version it works, but I need to be able to debug from time to time.
Help is appreciated.
Best
Patrick

New app on NET 4.8? So many improvements since EF Core 3.1... Try to do not scafolld all tables, I don't believe you need all of them.

In a sense, the memory taken by debugging has nothing to do with any database of any size. What matters is: how much data do you read into memory? Too much, apparently. We can't help you without seeing more details.

@GertArnold, 800 classes and huge OnModelCreating, I think debgugger may surrender.

@marc_s: does not really help regarding the issue. Furthermore, I think, everybody is understanding what I mean: with ADO.NET I have to use SQL-queries and transform the results to fit the OOP paradigm. On the other hand:  using EF Core, an ORM, the former is not necessary and programming with it feels like really awesome...

Where exactly does the exception occur?

If just "starting" out, you should be starting with a "smaller" set than 3GB. The "production" database is used for data analysis while building the new app. Partitioning the problem.
